# React native determine when text is cut off

Tags: ios, react-native, word-wrap

I am using react-native with a limited number of lines, that are shown as `...` using

```
<Text numberOfLines={4}> {myText} </Text>
```

Now my issue is, if the text is cut off I would like to show it some special image, to navigate to a new view. I am wondering whether there is a property i can use to test if the text is being cut off?

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a property for this right now (unfortunately).

There's a feature request here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2496 (also some suggestions of how you could get it working, but the implementation links are down).

You could measure the space occupied by a certain number of lines, then handle it yourself? But not ideal.

Answer (score 10):

There's now a new event called `onTextLayout` which can give you the number of lines in your text. Once you fetch this number, you could check if it's greater than the max number of lines you want to have, and if that's the case you can set some state that adds a `numberOfLines` prop and can be also used to determine if the text was truncated.

Here's an example of how you could get the number of lines:

```
 <Text
  onTextLayout={(e) => console.log("Number of lines: " + e.nativeEvent.lines.length) }
>
  {someText}                
</Text>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This not work on iOS.
On iOS lines.length equals to numberOfLines prop if the text is truncated.

Answer (score 2):

[react-native-read-more-text](https://github.com/expo/react-native-read-more-text/blob/master/index.js) detects it like this:

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    // ...

    // Get the height of the text with no restriction on number of lines
    const fullHeight = await measureHeightAsync(this._text);
    this.setState({ measured: true });
    await nextFrameAsync();

    if (!this._isMounted) {
      return;
    }

    // Get the height of the text now that number of lines has been set
    const limitedHeight = await measureHeightAsync(this._text);

    if (fullHeight > limitedHeight) {
      this.setState({ doWhatYouWant: true });
    }
  }
```

```js
function measureHeightAsync(component) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    component.measure((x, y, w, h) => {
      resolve(h);
    });
  });
}
```

---

If you want to display any element (text, button, etc.), you can use it like so:

```js
export class DescriptionCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { text } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.cardLabel}>
          <BoldText style={styles.cardLabelText}>
            Description
          </BoldText>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.cardBody}>
            <ReadMore
              numberOfLines={3}
              renderTruncatedFooter={this._renderTruncatedFooter}
              renderRevealedFooter={this._renderRevealedFooter}
              onReady={this._handleTextReady}>
              <RegularText style={styles.cardText}>
                {text}
              </RegularText>
            </ReadMore>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _renderTruncatedFooter = (handlePress) => {
    return (
      <RegularText style={{color: Colors.tintColor, marginTop: 5}} onPress={handlePress}>
        Read more
      </RegularText>
    );
  }

  _renderRevealedFooter = (handlePress) => {
    return (
      <RegularText style={{color: Colors.tintColor, marginTop: 5}} onPress={handlePress}>
        Show less
      </RegularText>
    );
  }

  _handleTextReady = () => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. It is fine if you want to place the "Read More" component under the text. What if you want to place it inline with the text? Like how apps like Facebook, Insta, or Quora do it?

Comment: @KashishGrover who talked about "place it inline with the text"?

Comment: The question was to show something special when the text is cut off. You can either render what you want, and for inline positioning, play with style as you already know it. You could also inspect the module source code to understand how they calculate the cut off.

Comment: The question specifically asks whether there is a way to determine if the text is cut off or not. That is all it asks. Your answer makes sense as a small use case for that but the question does not demand a use case. It demands a way of knowing whether/where the text is cut off.

Comment: I updated the answer for those that are not able to click on a link :)

Comment: I have shared my answer :)

Comment: ReadMore is not working inside FlatList Item. In side Flat list only works for initial visible items not for all items

Answer (score 2):

I answered a related question here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60500348/5449850

This has been a requirement in almost every React Native app that I have worked on so far. I finally have a solution, and I have open sourced it.

https://github.com/kashishgrover/react-native-see-more-inline

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-see-more-inline

As I mentioned in the repo,

> My motivation of building this was that I couldn't find any library/implementation that would place the "see more" link inline with the text. All the other implementations I found would place the link under the text. **This package uses text width, and using a simple binary search it (almost) accurately calculates where it should place the "see more" link.**

I am not sure if this is the most efficient solution out there, but it solves my use case. I will update the answer if and when I find a better solution.

This is what I did:

```
findTruncationIndex = async (containerWidth) => {
  if (
    this.containerWidthToTruncationIndexMap
    && this.containerWidthToTruncationIndexMap[containerWidth]
  ) {
    this.setState({ truncationIndex: this.containerWidthToTruncationIndexMap[containerWidth] });
    return;
  }

  const {
    children: text,
    style: { fontSize, fontFamily, fontWeight },
    seeMoreText,
    numberOfLines,
  } = this.props;

  const { width: textWidth } = await reactNativeTextSize.measure({
    text,
    fontSize,
    fontFamily,
    fontWeight,
  });

  const textWidthLimit = containerWidth * numberOfLines;

  if (textWidth < textWidthLimit) {
    this.setState({ truncationIndex: undefined });
    return;
  }

  const { width: seeMoreTextWidth } = await reactNativeTextSize.measure({
    text: ` ...${seeMoreText}`,
    fontSize,
    fontFamily,
    fontWeight,
  });

  const truncatedWidth = textWidthLimit - 2 * seeMoreTextWidth;

  let index = 0;
  let start = 0;
  let end = text.length - 1;

  while (start <= end) {
    const middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    const { width: partialWidth } = await reactNativeTextSize.measure({
      text: text.slice(0, middle),
      fontSize,
      fontFamily,
      fontWeight,
    });
    if (Math.abs(truncatedWidth - partialWidth) <= 10) {
      index = middle;
      break;
    } else if (partialWidth > truncatedWidth) {
      end = middle - 1;
    } else {
      start = middle + 1;
    }
  }

  const truncationIndex = Math.floor(index);

  // Map truncation index to width so that we don't calculate it again
  this.containerWidthToTruncationIndexMap = {
    ...this.containerWidthToTruncationIndexMap,
    [containerWidth]: truncationIndex,
  };
  this.setState({ truncationIndex });
};
```

You can see the full implementation of this component in the GitHub link that I shared above.

Answer (score 2):

`onTextLayout` provides `lines` array that we can use to check if text is truncated. On Android it's easy: `lines.length` is more than `numberOfLines` prop if the text is truncated.

On iOS `lines.length` equals to `numberOfLines` prop if the text is truncated. Unfortunately this happens also if your text fits exactly in `numberOfLines`. We can use the length and the width of the last line for heuristics that check if the text is cut off:

```
const IS_ANDROID = Platform.OS === 'android';
const MAX_LINE_COUNT = 4;

const ExpandableText = ({children, style}) => {
  const [numberOfLines, setNumberOfLines] = useState(MAX_LINE_COUNT);
  const [moreVisible, setMoreVisible] = useState(false);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  const handleLayout = (e) => {
    if (!IS_ANDROID)
      setWidth(e.nativeEvent.layout.width);
  }

  const handleTextLayout = (e) => {
    setMoreVisible(isTruncated(e.nativeEvent.lines));
  }

  const isTruncated = lines => {
    if (numberOfLines == 0 || lines.length < numberOfLines)
      return false;
    if (IS_ANDROID)
      return lines.length > numberOfLines;
    // lines.length equals to numberOfLines on iOS if text is truncated or it
    // takes exactly numberOfLines
    return lines[lines.length-1].text.length > lines[0].text.length ||
      lines[lines.length-1].width >= width * 0.82;
  }

  return (
    <View style={style}>
      <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={numberOfLines}
        onLayout={handleLayout} onTextLayout={handleTextLayout}>
        {children}
      </Text>
      { moreVisible &&
        <Pressable style={({ pressed }) => pressed ? {
          backgroundColor: 'lightgray'} : {}} hitSlop={20}
          onPress={() => setNumberOfLines(0)}>
          <Text style={styles.link}>More</Text>
        </Pressable>
      }
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -4):

The Text component has an onPress event which can be handled to navigate to another scene. To enable navigation, the component having the text should be placed in NavigationIOS component. Text component also has ellipsizeMode property which places "..." at the tail.

```
<Text 
  numberOfLines={4}
  ellipsizeMode="tail"
  onPress={(e) => this.props.navigator.push({component: Detail})}
>
  {myText}
</Text>
```

Comment: Smart solution!