# numberOfLines won't work on Android in React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering why `numberOfLines` won't set a limit of six lines while `maxLength` does work on the same `TextInput` and limits the user's input to 140 char.

Here's my code (simplified):

```
<TextInput
              maxLength={140}
              multiline={true}
              numberOfLines={6}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I leave you with the [TextInput React-Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) so you can check your current implementation, it is suggested to use multiline set to true, this could be causing the problem

```
<TextInput
  maxLength = {140}
  numberOfLines = {6}
  multiline={true} 
/>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but no I already did that and it doesn't work. Let me update my code snippet ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the [React-Native Text Input docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#numberoflines);

> numberOfLines?: number #
>
> Sets the number of lines for a TextInput. Use it with multiline set to
>   true to be able to fill the lines.

Did you set multiline prop to true?

Comment: Ok! I think I understood you wrong. numberOfLines doesn't supposed to limit the line number. It sets the initial number I think. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172095/2315280) there is a implementation with checking the size of the TextInput component.

Answer (score 0):

The `numberOfLine` props in **React Native** is just to set initial height of `TextInput` that can show text in the number of line you set in `numberOfLine`.

To do what you want you must do some code change in your `TexInput` maybe 
this reference link that i found to limit the number of line with the value of `numberOfLine` as paramater [number of line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172095/8323264) can solve your solution