# React Native - Adjust the font size based on the size of the container on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to put a text into a limited space (yellow container).
How to solve [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvDUO.png) in Android?

In iOS [the problem is solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdc80.png) with adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}.

My code:

```
<View
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    flex: 0.8,
    marginRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }}
>
  <CustomText style={{ fontWeight: '400' }}>{`Qt. ${orderProduct.quantity}`}</CustomText>
    <PriceText
      style={{
        fontWeight: '600',
        fontSize: 18,
        color: '#000'
      }}
      price={price}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: This question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001774/adjusts-font-size-to-fit-view-in-react-native-android

Answer (score 0):

Hey consider looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128215/react-native-to-limit-lines-in-textinput).
In android native it is done via setting max lines o a text to 1. `android:maxLines="1"`

Comment: In react native the same thing is done whit numberOfLines={1}, but the result is not what i want. For example if the price is very long then it will be truncated with '...' (12923.3...)

Comment: Yes that's the usual behavior. You must have set the width of layout specific.