# Is it possible to know how many lines of text are rendered by React Native when using numberOfLines prop?

Tags: react-native

The React Native numberOfLines prop is very useful but I want to programmatically adjust the height of my row between two numbers based on how many lines of text are actually rendered.

For example, I have a Text component of this form `<Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>{item.text}</Text>`

If the text is longer than two lines, it defaults to two lines as desired. But when it is less than two lines, it just shows a single line, again as desired. I just want to know when the content is a single lien versus two lines. Is there any way of finding this out?

Answer (score 6):

possible answer here
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632169/11816387)https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632169/11816387

I want to provide a modern solution. There is now a `onTextLayout` event that includes an array of lines which can be determined what number of lines are being rendered. There's other details in the `lines` array like actual height and width of every `line` which can be further used to determine if the text is being truncated.

```
const NUM_OF_LINES = 5;
const SOME_LONG_TEXT_BLOCK = 'Lorem ipsum ...';

function SomeComponent () { 
  const [ showMore, setShowMore ] = useState(false);
  const onTextLayout = useCallback(e =>
    setShowMore(e.nativeEvent.lines.length > NUM_OF_LINES);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Text numberOfLines={NUM_OF_LINES} onTextLayout={onTextLayout}>
      {SOME_LONG_TEXT_BLOCK}
    </Text>
  );
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, this works only with Android. iOS does return an array, but it's length is always 1, no matter how long the text is.

Answer (score 2):

In React Native, Text component has a props called onLayout

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#onlayout

with `{nativeEvent: {layout: {x, y, width, height}}}`

So first, have a state

```
state = {
  numOfLines: 0
}
```

Then in your Text component

```
<Text 
  numberOfLines={this.state.numOfLines}
  onLayout={(e) => { 
    this.setState({ numOfLines: e.nativeEvent.layout.height > YOUR_FONT_SIZE ? 2 : 1 })
  }
>
  {item.text}
</Text>
```

I am not totally sure with this solution because I just think it from my mind straight away. But, my logic is if your text height is more than your text fontSize it means that it is more than one line?

Let me know if it is work or not

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an npm package [react-native-text-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-text-size) will solve your problem.

From their docs:

```
const size = await rnTextSize.measure({
  text,             // text to measure, can include symbols
  width,            // max-width of the "virtual" container
  ...fontSpecs,     // RN font specification
})
```

"`size`" is not only the size, it has more info, one of which is `lineCount`, which is what you need.
Personally, I needed to send `allowFontScaling: false` in the `fontSpecs`, because we handle that internally.