# React native text component using number of lines

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to determine when the text will be truncated when using number of lines ? Have been searching everywhere and no clear answer. Thank you!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#numberoflines. That should work, unless you have a very specific use case. And by the way, if you can share any specific example or code, that would really help

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use [`numberOfLines`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#numberoflines) as a props for `<Text />` component. Its depend on the width of your component then calculate the length of the text. This prop is commonly used with [`ellipsizeMode`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#ellipsizemode).
Example:

```
<Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode='tail'>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! But this is the answer I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610538/is-it-possible-to-know-how-many-lines-of-text-are-rendered-by-react-native-when?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible with the `onTextLayout` event that includes an array of `lines` being rendered out. Simply looking at the length you can determine if you are at the limit. There's other details in the `lines` array like actual height and width of every line which can be further used to determine if the text is being truncated.

```
const NUM_OF_LINES = 5;
const SOME_LONG_TEXT_BLOCK = 'Fill in some long text yourself ...';

return (<Text
  numberOfLines={NUM_OF_LINES}
  onTextLayout={({ nativeEvent: { lines } }) =>
    setState({ showMoreButton: lines.length === NUM_OF_LINES })
  }
>
  {SOME_LONG_TEXT_BLOCK}
</Text>;
```

Comment: since which version is this available? currently I get an typescript error for this function and in the doc's is only a TODO marker https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#ontextlayout

Comment: I guess very recently since it's not even documented yet but I live on the bleeding edge so it works for me and will hopefully wok for others going forward.

Comment: We still can't use this, because if your text used up 2 lines (half on the second line), you still get `lines.length === 2`, which doesn't get truncated

Answer (score 5):

This works for me :)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { Text } from 'react-native'

export function MoreLessText({ children, numberOfLines }) {
  const [isTruncatedText, setIsTruncatedText] = useState(false)
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(true)

  return isTruncatedText ? (
    <>
      <Text numberOfLines={showMore ? numberOfLines : 0}>{children}</Text>
      <Text onPress={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>
        {showMore ? 'Read More' : 'Less'}
      </Text>
    </>
  ) : (
    <Text
      onTextLayout={(event) => {
        const { lines } = event.nativeEvent
        setIsTruncatedText(lines?.length > numberOfLines)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: For some reason in my project `lines` is an array of type `TextLayoutLine` and length is useless

Answer (score 0):

To create an instagram style comment with read more i did this (note that i'm using tailwind for styling, since this is a react-native app, the lib is `nativewind`, i'm also using a nested text which is allowing me to do a web html `<span>` element):

```
const [more, setMore] = useState(false)

const toggleShowMore = () => {
 setMore(!more)
}
<View className=" pl-1 pt-1 flex-row flex-1 max-w-[82%]">
    <Text numberOfLines={!more ? 3 : undefined}>
         <Text onPress={() => navigateUser(comment.user.username)} className="font-bold">
                @{comment.user?.username}{' '}
         </Text>{' '}
         <Text onPress={toggleShowMore}>{comment.content}</Text>
     </Text>
 </View>
```