# How to show for text More/Less in React-Native (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, react-native, text, react-native-flatlist

I am developing react-native application. In that, We are showing some description on **Text**, It may be number of lines.

So, If data has more than 3 lines, I have to show More and Less if it's expanded.

```
        <FlatList
          style={styles.faltList}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator
          data={data}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={styles.flatListCell}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>{item.description}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          )
          }
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
            <View style={{ height: 10}} />
          )}
        />
```

I have found **react-native-view-more-text** library, But I would like to implement it by custom code.

Note: I am displaying that Text in FlatList.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 44):

I tried in this way, Hope it helps to you and others!

```js
const postTextContent = (props) => {
const [textShown, setTextShown] = useState(false); //To show ur remaining Text
const [lengthMore,setLengthMore] = useState(false); //to show the "Read more & Less Line"
const toggleNumberOfLines = () => { //To toggle the show text or hide it
    setTextShown(!textShown);
}

const onTextLayout = useCallback(e =>{
    setLengthMore(e.nativeEvent.lines.length >=4); //to check the text is more than 4 lines or not
    // console.log(e.nativeEvent);
},[]);
    
  return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Text
              onTextLayout={onTextLayout}
              numberOfLines={textShown ? undefined : 4}
              style={{ lineHeight: 21 }}>{Your Long Text}</Text>

              {
                  lengthMore ? <Text
                  onPress={toggleNumberOfLines}
                  style={{ lineHeight: 21, marginTop: 10 }}>{textShown ? 'Read less...' : 'Read more...'}</Text>
                  :null
              }
      </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Worked fine! Thanks

Comment: What if I want to inline Read Less or Read More? To be precise, after ... are added by ellipses, I want to add Read More or Read Less? How this solution would work in that case

Comment: That works fine,Thanks. just notice that the condition must be greater than numberOfLines and not greater or equal.

Comment: @Ankit The onTextLayout doesn't work to get the length. if i make lengthMore state as true, then this works but the Read more text is present permanently, no matter what the length of text is.... Any idea how to make this work? https://snack.expo.dev/vhn0ZM3Pn

Comment: For some insane reason, the above is not working in Snack but is working in AVD.

Comment: No complications. Just copy and paste. Working source. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The first implementation is close but the problem is that the Read More button shows when the text equals 3 lines which it should not because there is no more text.  I fixed it by updating the number of lines in state as well as checking if the text had been shown or not.

```
const ReadMoreText = ({ readMoreStyle, text, textStyle }) => {
  const [showMoreButton, setShowMoreButton] = useState(false);
  const [textShown, setTextShown] = useState(false);
  const [numLines, setNumLines] = useState(undefined);

  const toggleTextShown = () => {
    setTextShown(!textShown);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setNumLines(textShown ? undefined : 3);
  }, [textShown]);

  const onTextLayout = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.nativeEvent.lines.length > 3 && !textShown) {
        setShowMoreButton(true);
        setNumLines(3);
      }
    },
    [textShown],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Text onTextLayout={onTextLayout} numberOfLines={numLines} style={textStyle} ellipsizeMode="tail">
        {text}
      </Text>

      {showMoreButton ? (
        <Text onPress={toggleTextShown} style={readMoreStyle}>
          {textShown ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'}
        </Text>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did this exact solution but app seems so slow when  I click on bigger texts

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `numberOfLines`, which is a `<Text>` prop:

> Used to truncate the text with an ellipsis after computing the text
>   layout, including line wrapping, such that the total number of lines
>   does not exceed this number.

And, obviously, an adequate logic handler to save in your `state` which text is shown and which is truncated.

Let's see an example I've just created:

```
state = {
    textShown: -1,
  };

  toggleNumberOfLines = index => {
    this.setState({
      textShown: this.state.textShown === index ? -1 : index,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            { key: 'a', description: longText },
            { key: 'b', description: longText },
            { key: 'c', description: longText },
          ]}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={styles.flatListCell}>
              <Text
                numberOfLines={this.state.textShown === index ? undefined : 3}
                style={styles.description}>
                {longText}
              </Text>
              <Text
                onPress={() => this.toggleNumberOfLines(index)}
                style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                {this.state.textShown === index ? 'read less...' : 'read more...'}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Here I use `state` to save the index of the element in the `FlatList` which is shown. If none is shown, then the value saved is -1.

You can try its behavior in [this](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/adequate-scones) snack, that (I hope) reproduces your case.
Let me know if this is what you're looking for.
(Hi, Anilkumar, we've already met :) )

Comment: Thank you. But, If I expand, The data is overlapping with cell header and while expanding time, Text height is increasing to above instead of footer increase, How to fix this?

Comment: And one more issue, If the text length is only 3 lines, then we are not showing More/Less, But, In this code showing More/Less even if the data has 3 lines only.

Comment: First one I think is a style problem. Second one it's an issue I've not considered and it is not so easy to fix, but you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986135/7581249) solution

Comment: Oh. Thank you @Milore

Answer (score 1):

take a look over my solution, I did not use text lines, I used text length instead.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const PostContent = () => {
  const postDescription =
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.postContentContainer}>
      {postDescription.length > 120 ? (
        showMore ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>
            <Text style={styles.postDescription}>{postDescription}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.seeMore}>Show less</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>
            <Text style={styles.postDescription}>
              {`${postDescription.slice(0, 120)}... `}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.seeMore}>Show more</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.postDescription}>{postDescription}</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default PostContent;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  postContentContainer: {
    // borderWidth: 1,
    // borderColor: 'red',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },

  postMedia: {
    //borderWidth: 1,
    //borderColor: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    height: 280,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },

  postDescription: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    color: colors.text.black,
    fontFamily: fonts.family.body,
    fontSize: fonts.fontSizes.button,
    fontWeight: fonts.fontWeights.thin,
  },

  seeMore: {
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    color: colors.text.grey,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    fontFamily: fonts.family.body,
    fontSize: fonts.fontSizes.button,
    fontWeight: fonts.fontWeights.thin,
  },
});
```

Comment: In general this is a good idea for a normal text but consider following: If there is a text starting with 30 line breaks this isn't a optimal solution because than you would have a length of 0 or 1 but the text is not truncated

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I have developed a very optimal, lightweight solution to this. I call it [react-native-more-or-less](https://github.com/rarenatoe/react-native-more-or-less)

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
import { MoreOrLess } from "react-native-more-or-less";

// ...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MoreOrLess numberOfLines={3} textComponent={CustomText}>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
      1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
      make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
      also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
      sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
      Ipsum.
    </MoreOrLess>
  );
}
```

Stats: https://bundlephobia.com/package/react-native-more-or-less@0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I gave a look at the react-native `Text` component when I was trying to find a way to limit the number of lines, but allowing the text to expand, and although it can truncate text to an amount of lines you specify, it doesn't show if the text was actually truncated or not.

This means that you can add a button to show more text, but it will show up even if the text was not truncated.

If truncating based on an amount of characters is acceptable, you can create a component that accepts react elements (it doesn't need to be just strings), parse the input, access the children of the elements until you reach a string, then count the amount of chars in the string, truncating and stopping the process after the maximum amount of chars is reached.

The following is an example of a component to do that:

```tsx
import React from 'react';

type ParseResult = {
    content: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    remaining: number;
};

type Parse = (root: ParseResult, parse: Parse) => ParseResult;

const parseString = (text: string, remaining: number): ParseResult => {
    if (!text?.length) {
        return { content: text, remaining };
    }

    const newText =
        remaining <= 0
            ? ''
            : text.length > remaining
            ? text.substring(0, remaining)
            : text;

    return { content: newText, remaining: remaining - text.length };
};

const parse: Parse = (root, parseCallback) => {
    const { content, remaining = 0 } = root;

    if (typeof content === 'string') {
        const result = parseString(content, remaining);
        return result;
    } else if (React.isValidElement(content)) {
        const children = (content.props as { children?: React.ReactNode })
            ?.children;

        if (children != null) {
            const innerResult = parseCallback(
                {
                    content: children,
                    remaining,
                },
                parseCallback,
            );
            const newContent = React.cloneElement(content, {}, innerResult.content);
            return { content: newContent, remaining: innerResult.remaining };
        }
    } else if (Array.isArray(content)) {
        const list: React.ReactNode[] = [];
        let newRemaining = remaining;

        for (const child of content) {
            const parsed = parseCallback(
                { content: child, remaining: newRemaining },
                parseCallback,
            );
            newRemaining = parsed.remaining;
            const newContent = (
                <React.Fragment key={list.length}>{parsed.content}</React.Fragment>
            );
            list.push(newContent);

            if (newRemaining < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return { content: list, remaining: newRemaining };
    }

    return root;
};

export interface ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    expanded?: boolean;
    showMore?: React.ReactNode;
    showLess?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ReadMoreInner: React.FC<
    {
        children: React.ReactNode;
        truncate: number;
    } & ReadMoreAdditionalProps
> = ({ truncate, expanded, showMore, showLess, children }) => {
    const root: ParseResult = {
        content: children,
        remaining: truncate,
    };
    const result = parse(root, parse);

    return (
        <>
            {expanded ? children : result.content}
            {result.remaining < 0 ? (expanded ? showLess : showMore) : undefined}
        </>
    );
};

export interface ReadMoreOptions extends ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    truncate?: number;
}

export type ReadMoreProps = ReadMoreOptions & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ReadMore: React.FC<ReadMoreProps> = ({
    truncate,
    children,
    ...props
}) => {
    return truncate != null ? (
        <ReadMoreInner {...props} truncate={truncate}>
            {children}
        </ReadMoreInner>
    ) : (
        <>{children}</>
    );
};
```

Keep in mind that this component expects the children components to contain the final text (or no text). It won't access other properties (like a `text` or `title` property), they will be ignored.

You can just include this component in your code, add buttons to show more or less text and then style the buttons the way you want.

I created a library to do this if you prefer to not have to maintain the component code in your project.

Install the library with:

```tsx
npm install react-shorten
```

Below is an example of how to use the library:

```tsx
import React from 'react';
import { ReadMore } from 'react-shorten';
import type { StyleProp, TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export interface ReadMoreNativeProps {
    truncate: number | undefined;
    showMoreText?: React.ReactNode;
    showLessText?: React.ReactNode;
    style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
    btnStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const ReadMoreNative: React.FC<ReadMoreNativeProps> = ({
    truncate,
    showMoreText,
    showLessText,
    style,
    btnStyle,
    children,
}) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

    const onShowMore = React.useCallback(() => setExpanded(true), []);

    const onShowLess = React.useCallback(() => setExpanded(false), []);

    return (
        <ReadMore
            truncate={truncate}
            expanded={expanded}
            showMore={
                <Text style={style}>
                    {'... '}
                    <Text onPress={onShowMore} style={btnStyle}>
                        {showMoreText ?? 'Show more'}
                    </Text>
                </Text>
            }
            showLess={
                <Text style={style}>
                    {' '}
                    <Text onPress={onShowLess} style={btnStyle}>
                        {showLessText ?? 'Show less'}
                    </Text>
                </Text>
            }
        >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,{' '}
            <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}>
                <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>
                    consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper, odio eu aliquam
                    ultricies, enim sapien aliquet arcu, quis aliquam diam massa eu
                    nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget nunc ullamcorper aliquet.
                </Text>
            </Text>{' '}
            Sed euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies, justo nisl aliquet nunc,
            quis aliquam diam massa eu nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget nunc
            ullamcorper aliquet.
        </ReadMore>
    );
};
```

You can see a web demo [here](https://lucasbasquerotto.github.io/react-read-more/) and a native demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@lucasbasquerotto/react-shorten).

You can also use the demos as references and include the `ReadMore` component above directly in your project, if you prefer to not install another library (as asked in the OP).

Regarding the OP code specifically, the code specified as `<Text style={styles.description}>{item.description}</Text>` should be included inside the `ReadMore` component.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AnchorText from '../AnchorText';

import { StyledContainer, RegularText } from './styles';

export default class Description extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  showMore: true,
};
}

 onClick = () => {
this.setState({
  showMore: false,
});
};

 render() {
const { description } = this.props;
const { showMore } = this.state;
if (!description) return null;

return (
  <StyledContainer FD={'column'}>
    {showMore ? (
      <RegularText MT={1}>
        {description.slice(0, 150)}{' '}
        {description.length > 150 && (
          <AnchorText onClick={this.onClick} label=" .. Read more" />
        )}{' '}
      </RegularText>
    ) : (
        <RegularText MT={1}>{description}</RegularText>
    )}
  </StyledContainer>
);
 }
} 

Description.propTypes = {
 description: PropTypes.string,
 };
```

Check out this Widget

Comment: What are these PropTypes, AnchorText?

Comment: just Proptype checking . ignore them

Comment: And what is AnchorText?

Comment: just Clickable text

Answer (score -2):

[check output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6hMp.png)

```
state = {
    textLenth: null,
    numberOfLines: 3,
}
```

```
handleSeeMore = () => {
    this.state.textLenth
    ? this.setState({numberOfLines: 0})
    : this.setState({numberOfLines: 3});
};
```

```
     <Text
     numberOfLines={this.state.numberOfLines}
     onPress={() => this.handleSeeMore()}
     ellipsizeMode="middle"
     onTextLayout={({nativeEvent: {lines}}) =>
     this.setState({textLenth: lines.length === 3})
     }>
         This Gig Take a glance at the showcase of our artistic work:
         Modern and Trendy Logo Artworkslkjfkljf ksnfksfnsf Mascot &
         Custom Logo efdfg Artworks:lk knnk 'Explore the
         ultimate Experience..!' To fulfill your designing needs, 
         Make us Graphically Yours...!! Why Team StrideInIt? We 
         believe in our
     {'                      '}
         {this.state.textLenth && (
         <Text
         color="red"
         onPress={() => this.setState({numberOfLines: 0})}>
             see more
         </Text>
         )}
     </Text>
```