# Show More/ Less Text in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to find a way to have show more/less text if there are more than 3 lines of text.  I have tried the [react-show-more-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-show-more-text) package but it was very buggy so the closest I have been able to get is the top answer in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805233/how-to-show-for-text-more-less-in-react-naitve-javascript/62079722#62079722)
The main issue is that if there are **only** 3 lines its showing the read more/less text also.  It should be show if there would actually be another line of text when you hit the button.  My code.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const ReadMoreText = ({ readMoreStyle, text, textStyle }) => {
  const [textShown, setTextShown] = useState(false);
  const [lengthMore, setLengthMore] = useState(false);

  const toggleNumberOfLines = () => {
    setTextShown(!textShown);
  };

  const onTextLayout = useCallback((e) => {
    setLengthMore(e.nativeEvent.lines.length >= 3);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Text onTextLayout={onTextLayout} numberOfLines={textShown ? undefined : 3} style={textStyle}>
        {text}
      </Text>

      {lengthMore ? (
        <Text onPress={toggleNumberOfLines} style={readMoreStyle}>
          {textShown ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'}
        </Text>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default ReadMoreText;
```

Comment: Is there just change `>= 3` to `>3` ?

Comment: that does not work.  wish it was that easy.  in that case it would be like 4 which means you have to change the numberOfLines also.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the number of lines needs to be updated in state.  With what I was previously doing it was being overwritten to three every time.

```
const ReadMoreText = ({ readMoreStyle, text, textStyle }) => {
  const [showMoreButton, setShowMoreButton] = useState(false);
  const [textShown, setTextShown] = useState(false);
  const [numLines, setNumLines] = useState(undefined);

  const toggleTextShown = () => {
    setTextShown(!textShown);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setNumLines(textShown ? undefined : 3);
  }, [textShown]);

  const onTextLayout = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.nativeEvent.lines.length > 3 && !textShown) {
        setShowMoreButton(true);
        setNumLines(3);
      }
    },
    [textShown],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Text onTextLayout={onTextLayout} numberOfLines={numLines} style={textStyle} ellipsizeMode="tail">
        {text}
      </Text>

      {showMoreButton ? (
        <Text onPress={toggleTextShown} style={readMoreStyle}>
          {textShown ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'}
        </Text>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one rabbit hole that react native never bothers with.
There are some options out there for react native, but even the most popular isn't done in typescript and lacks a lot of care.

**So I made my own solution:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rntext/more-or-less**

I would appreciate it if you tried it and let me know if it fits your model and if not, maybe how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a look at the react-native `Text` component when I was trying to find a way to limit the number of lines, but allowing the text to expand, and although it can truncate text to an amount of lines you specify, it doesn't show if the text was actually truncated or not.

This means that you can add a button to show more text, but it will show up even if the text was not truncated (which seems to be your issue).

If truncating based on an amount of characters is acceptable (instead of truncating the amount of lines), you can create a component that accepts react elements (it doesn't need to be just strings), parse the input, access the children of the elements until you reach a string, then count the amount of chars in the string, truncating and stopping the process after the maximum amount of chars is reached.

The following is an example of a component to do that:

```tsx
import React from 'react';

type ParseResult = {
    content: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    remaining: number;
};

type Parse = (root: ParseResult, parse: Parse) => ParseResult;

const parseString = (text: string, remaining: number): ParseResult => {
    if (!text?.length) {
        return { content: text, remaining };
    }

    const newText =
        remaining <= 0
            ? ''
            : text.length > remaining
            ? text.substring(0, remaining)
            : text;

    return { content: newText, remaining: remaining - text.length };
};

const parse: Parse = (root, parseCallback) => {
    const { content, remaining = 0 } = root;

    if (typeof content === 'string') {
        const result = parseString(content, remaining);
        return result;
    } else if (React.isValidElement(content)) {
        const children = (content.props as { children?: React.ReactNode })
            ?.children;

        if (children != null) {
            const innerResult = parseCallback(
                {
                    content: children,
                    remaining,
                },
                parseCallback,
            );
            const newContent = React.cloneElement(content, {}, innerResult.content);
            return { content: newContent, remaining: innerResult.remaining };
        }
    } else if (Array.isArray(content)) {
        const list: React.ReactNode[] = [];
        let newRemaining = remaining;

        for (const child of content) {
            const parsed = parseCallback(
                { content: child, remaining: newRemaining },
                parseCallback,
            );
            newRemaining = parsed.remaining;
            const newContent = (
                <React.Fragment key={list.length}>{parsed.content}</React.Fragment>
            );
            list.push(newContent);

            if (newRemaining < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return { content: list, remaining: newRemaining };
    }

    return root;
};

export interface ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    expanded?: boolean;
    showMore?: React.ReactNode;
    showLess?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ReadMoreInner: React.FC<
    {
        children: React.ReactNode;
        truncate: number;
    } & ReadMoreAdditionalProps
> = ({ truncate, expanded, showMore, showLess, children }) => {
    const root: ParseResult = {
        content: children,
        remaining: truncate,
    };
    const result = parse(root, parse);

    return (
        <>
            {expanded ? children : result.content}
            {result.remaining < 0 ? (expanded ? showLess : showMore) : undefined}
        </>
    );
};

export interface ReadMoreOptions extends ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    truncate?: number;
}

export type ReadMoreProps = ReadMoreOptions & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ReadMore: React.FC<ReadMoreProps> = ({
    truncate,
    children,
    ...props
}) => {
    return truncate != null ? (
        <ReadMoreInner {...props} truncate={truncate}>
            {children}
        </ReadMoreInner>
    ) : (
        <>{children}</>
    );
};
```

Keep in mind that this component expects the children components to contain the final text (or no text). It won't access other properties (like a `text` or `title` property), they will be ignored.

You can just include this component in your code, add buttons to show more or less text and then style the buttons the way you want.

I created a library to do this if you prefer to not have to maintain the component code in your project.

Install the library with:

```tsx
npm install react-shorten
```

Below is an example of how to use the library:

```tsx
import React from 'react';
import { ReadMore } from 'react-shorten';
import type { StyleProp, TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export interface ReadMoreNativeProps {
    truncate: number | undefined;
    showMoreText?: React.ReactNode;
    showLessText?: React.ReactNode;
    style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
    btnStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const ReadMoreNative: React.FC<ReadMoreNativeProps> = ({
    truncate,
    showMoreText,
    showLessText,
    style,
    btnStyle,
    children,
}) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

    const onShowMore = React.useCallback(() => setExpanded(true), []);

    const onShowLess = React.useCallback(() => setExpanded(false), []);

    return (
        <ReadMore
            truncate={truncate}
            expanded={expanded}
            showMore={
                <Text style={style}>
                    {'... '}
                    <Text onPress={onShowMore} style={btnStyle}>
                        {showMoreText ?? 'Show more'}
                    </Text>
                </Text>
            }
            showLess={
                <Text style={style}>
                    {' '}
                    <Text onPress={onShowLess} style={btnStyle}>
                        {showLessText ?? 'Show less'}
                    </Text>
                </Text>
            }
        >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,{' '}
            <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}>
                <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>
                    consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper, odio eu aliquam
                    ultricies, enim sapien aliquet arcu, quis aliquam diam massa eu
                    nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget nunc ullamcorper aliquet.
                </Text>
            </Text>{' '}
            Sed euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies, justo nisl aliquet nunc,
            quis aliquam diam massa eu nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget nunc
            ullamcorper aliquet.
        </ReadMore>
    );
};
```

You can see a web demo [here](https://lucasbasquerotto.github.io/react-read-more/) and a native demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@lucasbasquerotto/react-shorten).